# UNIX string comparing in large file

Tags: unix, grep, string-manipulation

I have a large text file with over 75 Million records. Each record consists of string tokens (attributes) and between each token there is a tab character. This is an example of two records:

```
43    ao489fer809    abcdefghikl    1.41    0

81    ijfij03iuff    abcdefghikl e89rt904i3 094utofgimf    0.13    1
```

So each record consists of 5 tokens (notice that the third token includes the space character).

Now let's suppose I have the string "abcdefghikl" -let's call it the key-. I am interested at the third token. So I want to compare the key to the third token and if the token is **exactly** the key (and doesn't just contain the key as my second record), to write the winning record to a new file. Any grep ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `awk` in this situation

```
awk -F"\t" '$3 == "abcdefghikl" {print}' filename > outputfile
```

Where you set the seperator to a tab, and the print only the lines where the third column matches the key.

Comment: Agreed, I was going to pipe sed in because I forgot how to set the separator.  then direct to new file _filename > newfile.txt_

Comment: @nerdwaller You can also set the field separator inside the script, but it doesn't make a difference afaik.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: This doesn't work for the second of the two records.

Comment: @Bernhard Thanks, I just started learning the magic of awk & sed.  I'll definitely note that one!

Answer (score 0):

## grep

```
$ cat -v td
43      ao489fer809     abcdefghikl     1.41    0
81      ijfij03iuff     abcdefghikl e89rt904i3 094utofgimf      0.13    1

$ grep -P '\tabcdefghikl\t' td
43      ao489fer809     abcdefghikl     1.41    0
```

or if finicky

```
$ grep -P '^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\tabcdefghikl\t' td
43      ao489fer809     abcdefghikl     1.41    0
```

Comment: The `awk` example you give, does exactly what @ddmichael is looking for.

Comment: Ah, I completely misunderstood! Answer revised.

Comment: Your first example would also match if the key were in the second column.